# Where does a callback function in javascript get its arguments from?

Tags: javascript, callback

I am able to run a code like this

```
myObject.save(function(error, data){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

What i don't understand is where the anonymous function get the arguments error and data from?

Comment: It gets it from whatever mechanism calls the callback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do the parameters in a javascript callback function come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624634/where-do-the-parameters-in-a-javascript-callback-function-come-from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its from the thing that calls it - so save might look like this:

```
    function save(callback) {
        //do stuff

        var error = false;
        var data = {
            something: 'horse'
        };

        callback(error, data)
    }
```

There's no magic going on - its just a function call

Comment: I guess the only thing to add here is that in javascript functions are first class citizens so you can pass them around just like you can other objects/ints etc.